# How to reference non-static variable name from static context?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that lets the user enter a team name.
Here is my code:

```
public class Team {
    public String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter name team");
        Scanner tn = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = tn.nextLine();     
    }
}
```

I understand that "non-static variable name cannot be referenced from a static context". I know that if I take the "static" away from the main then it will work, but:

a) How can I reference it without taking the "static" out?

b) Is there a way to get the users input and assign it straight to the variable "name" i.e. without the:

```
Scanner tn = new Scanner(System.in);
name = tn.nextLine();
```

Basic questions I know, but I am still a beginner! 
Many thanks,
Miles

Comment: main method has to be static, I don't think you can take it away...

Answer (score 4):

`name` is a team name. So you need to instantiate a new `Team` object and set its name :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter name team");
    Scanner tn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Team team = new Team();
    team.name = tn.nextLine();     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`static` methods do not allow to use the non-static variables directly because `non-static/instance` variables are initialized in memory on object creation. Hence you need to create an object of the the class and then use the variable. Do something like this:

```
Team teamObj = new Team();
//now access name variable using teabObj instance
teamObj.name = tn.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection as follows to access that non static field.

```
    System.out.println("Enter name team");
    Scanner tn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Team team=new Team();
    Field field=Team.class.getField("name");
    field.set(team,tn.next());
    System.out.println((String) field.get(team));
```

Live [demo](http://ideone.com/dY73bM) for reflection.

Or you can try as follows.

```
   Team team = new Team();
   team.name = tn.nextLine();
```

Live [demo](http://ideone.com/D1ZHMe)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Team object if you want.

```
Team team = new Team();
team.name = tn.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Static methods/variables are bound to class. They have no access to non-static variables ( they have no idea on which instance of class they should call the method). You have to create object, and then call the non-static method.